# Cmake Swift framework with C files - setting target membership and properties

Tags: ios, swift, cmake, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

I am trying to build a framework with a combination of swift and C files and using cmake to generate the XCode Project:

After generating the project using this command:

```
add_library(MyLibrary STATIC ${FLAT_LIBRARY_FILES})
set_target_properties(MyLibrary PROPERTIES
    FRAMEWORK TRUE
    MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER com.MyLibrary.MyLibrary
    # "current version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
    VERSION 16.4.0
    # "compatibility version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
    SOVERSION 1.0.0
    PUBLIC_HEADER MyLibrary.h
    DEFINES_MODULE YES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer")
```

with command:

```
cmake -G Xcode -B ./build/sdk/ios ./sdk/ios
```

but after this project is generated, I still have to do the following to be able to build the library for iOS:

1. Add iOS as platform
2. Add swift files to target (C files are added to the target correctly)
3. Set `defines_module` to true
4. Set `swift_version`
5. Uncheck test file from target
6. Make headers public

There have been scant documentation about dealing with this scenario and I have tried various set() commands that I was able to find, to no success. How can I handle this?